# Launch nodejs function from pug template

Tags: node.js, pug

I have a nodeJS server using express that is serving pages generated from a .pug.

I want to have a button on this .pug which launched a function on the nodeJS server.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you can use socket.io to listen for an event from the front end and respond from the backend. I think an easier solution would be to have the button request an express route which runs the function